# jquery slider question

Tags: jquery, slider

So i have this slider with a range. And usually, when I set the range, I don't want to change it while i'm moving about the period. So what I'm looking for is to move the slider range by clicking in the middle of it or something like that. I hope I'm clear enough. Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code/example of what you're doing currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default

It has the functionality that you need... 
I have been working a lot with customizing the jquery-ui slider, and there are many nice features and options with this slider.

Comment: that's what I'm using. I just mean, when I have a range, how do I move the slider without messing up the interval I have set but both values start and end at the same time.

Comment: Im not shure I understand the question.. do you have a link to a live preview of the problem.